# Facebook API: проблема с токеном

Tags: facebook-api

У меня проблема с токеном FB API. Все работало, но в какой то момент стало выдавать ошибку:

{'error': {'message': 'Error validating access token: Session has expired on Tuesday, 20-Jul-21 02:50:57 PDT. The current time is Thursday, 29-Jul-21 00:58:43 PDT.', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 190, 'error_subcode': 463, 'fbtrace_id': 'APxVQGMEvALKX0DSMdhgmBs'}}

Попробовал сгенерить новый токен с помощью:

curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app-id}&client_secret={app-secret}&grant_type=client_credentials"

Теперь ошибка такая:

{'error': {'message': 'No user access token specified', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 1, 'fbtrace_id': 'As07bkTUSXb5aq_YKWc3CAk'}}

Старый токен был длиной 185 символов, большие/маленькие латинские буквы и цифры. Новый - 43 символа, большие/маленкие латинские буквы, цифры и спецсимволы. Может быть надо как-то по другому генерить?

PS Также пробовал в url добавлять v9.0, как было у меня, но выдает тот же токен длиной 43 символа.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Токен можно получить по ссылке https://developers.facebook.com/apps

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]